# Formatting a mobile number to international format

Tags: python, python-2.7

A user can input a phone number in any of the following formats:

1. `07xxxxxxxxx`
2. `00447xxxxxxxxx`
3. `447xxxxxxxxx`
4. `+447xxxxxxxxx`

I need help in creating a function that will take the number in any of the formats above and return it as international format `+447xxxxxxxxx`.

This is what I have so far

```
def _clean_mobile(mobile):

  import re
  if re.match('^+44', mobile):
       return mobile
  elif re.match('^44', mobile):
       return "+" + mobile
```

Comment: and you are stuck because?

Comment: Sorry, but the preceding edits were wrong in every way. The suggested edit took several steps backward in needlessly adding the language name to the title as a prefix when the question was already tagged and moving the version-specific tag into the body of the post, then changing the ordered list to an unordered list for no apparent reason...then a reviewer re-introduced a typo that had been fixed in an earlier edit! I honestly can't comprehend what people are thinking sometimes when they edit or review suggested edits. :|

Comment: @njzk2, well a few reasons, I'm, not 100% sure if this is the best way to do it and I'm sure using re.match like this won't help me say if in the future I add 0771 or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://ideone.com/ErL7Y4

```
def standardizePhoneNumber(mobile):
import re
    valid_prefixes = '[+447|447|00447|07]'
result = re.match('^' + valid_prefixes + '*([0-9]{9})$', mobile)
if result:
    return '+447' + result.group(1)
else:
    return None # invalid format

print standardizePhoneNumber('07111111111')
print standardizePhoneNumber('00447111111111')
print standardizePhoneNumber('447111111111')
print standardizePhoneNumber('+447111111111')
print standardizePhoneNumber('456789456')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
FORMATS = ['^07', '^00447', '^447', '^\+447']
def sanitize(mobile):
    mobile = re.sub('\s+', '', mobile) # strip whitespaces
    for format in FORMATS:
        if re.match(format, mobile):
            return re.sub(format + '(\d{9})', '+447\g<1>', mobile)
    return mobile

sanitize('00447123456789')   # +447123456789
sanitize('07123456789')      # +447123456789
sanitize('447123456789')     # +447123456789
sanitize('+44 712 345 67 89')# +447123456789
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the possibly simple solution using Python's `format` method:

```
numbers= ['07345216342', '00447345216342', '447345216342', '+447345216342'] #input
for i in numbers:
    print '+447{0:0=9d}'.format(int(str(i)[-9:]))
```

Output:

```
+447345216342
+447345216342
+447345216342
+447345216342
```