# How to convert Mobile number to international format in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to convert mobile number to International format.

ex: if user enters the number in below format:

```
0274 123 4567(Newzeland)
09916123764(India)
```

Conversion should happen

```
+642741234567 (Newzeland)
+919916123764 (India)
```

Tried with lots of regular expressions, but just these are validating, but replace is not happening.

Found some similar link in Stack overflow, but it's in Python.

[Formatting a mobile number to international format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739475/formatting-a-mobile-number-to-international-format)

For normal mobile validation i am using below code.

```
protected bool IsValidPhone(string strPhoneInput)
{
    // Remove symbols (dash, space and parentheses, etc.)
    string strPhone = Regex.Replace(strPhoneInput, @"[- ()\*\!]", String.Empty);

    // Check for exactly 10 numbers left over
    Regex regTenDigits = new Regex(@"^([0|\+[0-9]{1,5})?([7-9][0-9]{9})$");
    Match matTenDigits = regTenDigits.Match(strPhone);

    return matTenDigits.Success;
}
```

Could any body tell us how to convert this into C#.

Comment: Users generally don't enter their phone number with spaces, and you shouldn't rely on that. Can't you just use a country dropdown? If you think you really need this, can you explain in words how you want it to work? Like _"if a phone number starts with 0 and has groups of 4-3-4 digits, it must be recognized as a New Zealand number, which replaces the first `0` with `+64`"_? And can you then tell what you have tried to solve _that_ specific problem for C#?

Comment: @CodeCaster: since i am using WCF service for this validation i can't use drop down, if user enters in the test client number  ex: 0274 123 4567, i have to replace the first 0 with +64.  adding the code for validations what i am using.

Comment: Then add a `string PhoneCountry` property to the request object?

Comment: @CodeCaster: could you elobarate, means do i need to add country codes in property statically and need to replace the leading zero with country code?

Comment: No, let the user specify the country of origin for the phone number they'll provide in that WCF call you're talking about. Then it's a simple dictionary lookup to prefix the number with the country code, if the user didn't already do that.

Comment: And what will happen if user meant to enter 0274 123 4567 but made a mistake and entered 00274 123 4567? As far as i know, 00 is equal to + for phone numbers. Will you take the number as +27 (country code)... or +64 274... ?

Comment: I wouldn't let users to send gsm no free formatted. I would suggest you to give them a schema like "country code" + "area code" + "phone number" or smth like this. So that, you would know what was intended.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Thank you, I will check with them.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions, i will check with service team regarding country codes. but just for stub creation i used the below code which is manageable.

private string IsMobileNumberValid(string mobileNumber)
        {

```
        // remove all non-numeric characters
        string _mobileNumber = CleanNumber(mobileNumber);

        // trim any leading zeros
        _mobileNumber = _mobileNumber.TrimStart(new char[] { '0' });

        // check for this in case they've entered 44 (0)xxxxxxxxx or similar
        if (_mobileNumber.StartsWith("+640"))
        {
            _mobileNumber = _mobileNumber.Remove(2, 1);
        }

        // add country code if they haven't entered it
        //If we need to handle with multiple Country codes we have to place a list here,Currently added +64 as per document.
        if (!_mobileNumber.StartsWith("+64"))
        {
            _mobileNumber = "+64" + _mobileNumber;
        }

        // check if it's the right length
        if (_mobileNumber.Length != 12)
        {
            return _mobileNumber;
        }

        return _mobileNumber;
    }

    public string CleanNumber(string phone)
    {
        Regex digitsOnly = new Regex(@"[^\d]");
        return digitsOnly.Replace(phone, "");
    }
```

Comment: Since `_mobileNumber` is the result from a call to `CleanNumber`, the first if statement will always be false and the second will always be true.

Answer (score 13):

For posterity's sake, here is a c# port of Google's LibPhoneNumber ([official repository](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber)). The library provides a variety of methods for validating and formatting phone numbers.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/libphonenumber-csharp/

An example with this library.

```
string localPhoneNumber = "(555) 555-5555"
PhoneNumber pn = PhoneNumberUtil.Instance.Parse(localPhoneNumber, "US");
string internationalPhoneNumber = pn.Format(PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL);
//result +1-555-555-5555
```

Comment: The syntax seems to have changed. I cant get it to compile.

Answer (score 10):

[farlee2121](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2436737/farlee2121)'s answer is deprecated. Now when using the [libphonenumber-csharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/libphonenumber-csharp/) package your task should be done this way:

```
string phoneNumber = Console.ReadLine();
PhoneNumber pn = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance().Parse(phoneNumber, "US");
string internationalPhoneNumber = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance().Format(pn, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL);
```